# Nuxeo vs Alfresco Community Edition

Tags: ecm, alfresco, nuxeo

Hi I am evaluating Nuxeo and Alfresco Community Edition as ECM. Have you got any experience with them to share? Any comparison?

Comment: This question is off topic per the FaQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bought CMS Watch's [ECM Report](http://www.eiwatch.com/Research/Channel/ECM/), it contains a very detailed comparison. It is not free though :-(

And all other comparisons I could find are already quite old... sorry :-/

Try asking on Nuxeo and Alfresco's forums.